# Pins not being shown using Parse.com

Tags: ios, annotations, parse-platform

I am trying to add pins to a couple of locations I created in one of my classes, which is called "Places".

The key to these locations is defined as "places_coordinates".

I tried to place those pins as follows:

```
View Controller.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>


@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property(nonatomic, strong) MKPinAnnotationView *geoPointAnnotation;
@property(nonatomic, strong)MKPointAnnotation *annotation;
@property(nonatomic, strong)CLLocation *location;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *detailItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *appleMap;


@end


ViewController.m


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad]; 

    if (nil == self.locationManager){ 

        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; 

        self.locationManager.delegate = self; 

        //Configure Accuracy depending on your needs, default is kCLLocationAccuracyBest 

        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer; 

        // Set a movement threshold for new events. 

        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 500; // meters 

        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; 

        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; 

        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]; 

    } 



    self.appleMap.delegate = self; 

    // Map will show current location 

    self.appleMap.showsUserLocation = YES; 


    // Maps' opening spot 

    self.location = [self.locationManager location]; 

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateActual = [self.location coordinate]; 

    // Map's zoom 

    MKCoordinateSpan zoom = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.010, 0.010); 

    // Create a region 

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinateActual, zoom); 

    // Method which sets exibition method 

    [self.appleMap setRegion:region animated:YES]; 

    //Map's type 

    self.appleMap.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard; 


}


#pragma mark - Location Manager Callbacks



-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{ 


    [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) { 

        if (!error) { 

            // Create Object 

            PFObject *offersLocation = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Places"]; 

            //Create a point for markers 

            PFGeoPoint *offersPoint = offersLocation[@"places_coordinate"]; 

            // Check current Location 

             NSLog(@"%@", offersPoint); 

            // Create a query for Places of interest near current location 

            PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Places"]; 

            [query whereKey:@"places_coordinate" nearGeoPoint:geoPoint withinKilometers:5.0]; 

            NSLog(@"Query: %@",query); 

            // Limit the query 

            query.limit = 10; 

            // Store objects in the array
            NSArray *offersArray = [query findObjects]; 

            NSLog(@"Array: %@",offersArray); 

            if (!error) { 

                for (query in offersArray) { 



                    self.annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] 

                                                             init]; 

                    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {offersPoint.latitude, offersPoint.longitude}; 

                    self.annotation.coordinate = coord ; 

                    [self.appleMap addAnnotation:self.annotation]; 

                    NSLog(@"Annotation: %@",self.annotation); 

                } 

            } 

        } 

    }]; 

}



#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{ 

    static NSString *MapViewAnnotationIdentifier = @"places_coordinate"; 

    MKPinAnnotationView *pinOffers = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:self.annotation reuseIdentifier:MapViewAnnotationIdentifier]; 

    pinOffers.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed; 

    pinOffers.canShowCallout = YES; 

    pinOffers.animatesDrop = YES; 

    return pinOffers; 

}
```

My log is showing all offers inside the offersArray, but I am not finding a way of putting markers in it.

I also tried a couple of other topics, but did not really get it:

[how to add multiple pin at the same lat/long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862775/how-to-add-multiple-pin-at-the-same-lat-long)

[Adding mapview annotations within parse query returns null randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585584/adding-mapview-annotations-within-parse-query-returns-null-randomly)

Best Regards,

Comment: I think I can help - just to clarify though, you are not seeing ANY pins on your map, and you want your pins to show up on the map, right?

Comment: Hi @RyanKreager , thanks for your reply. Yes, I can only see the current location one. The others I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was happening was that my for loop was not built correctly.

It should be like this:

```
...
if (!error) {
                for (PFObject *offerObject in offersArray) {


                    PFGeoPoint *offerPoint = [offerObject objectForKey:@"coordenadas"];

                    MKPointAnnotation *geoPointAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]
                                                             init];

                    geoPointAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(offerPoint.latitude, offerPoint.longitude);

                    [self.appleMap addAnnotation:geoPointAnnotation];

                    NSLog(@"Annotation: %@",geoPointAnnotation);

                }
            }

...
```