# Display an array of Parse PFGeoPoints as Map Annotations Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsarray, mkannotation

I am attempting to display objects stored in a NSArray on a map.  The objects are being pulled from a Parse.com class called Affiliates after a method to fetch locations within 2 miles of a user has been executed.  I have used NSLog to confirm that the query is executing correctly, so I know that the fetch is also being executed correctly.

When I try and run the app, I an error is thrown at the for(NSDictionary) section and the app freezes.  The error states "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (access code 1, address 0x80120)" After consulting with Google I see that it is some type of memory allocation issue, but I have no idea why it is occurring or how to fix it.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MapAnnotation.h"

@import CoreLocation;

@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *affiliates;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {


    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Ask for authorization to collect location from user
    CLLocationManager * locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    // Check for iOS 8. Without this guard the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.
    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {

        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    //Set map options
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
    self.mapView.userTrackingMode = YES;

    // Store the user's location as a Parse PFGeoPoint and call the fetchAffiliatesNearPoint method
    [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [self fetchAffiliatesNearPoint:geoPoint];
            NSLog(@"Got User Location! %@", geoPoint);
        }
    }];

    /* This is where I am having issues

    for(NSDictionary *affiliates in affiliates) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([affiliates[@"latitude"] doubleValue], [affiliates[@"longitude"] doubleValue]);

        MapAnnotation *annotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] init];
        annotation.coordinate = annotationCoordinate;
        annotation.title = affiliates[@"name"];
        annotation.subtitle = affiliates[@"url"];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    }

*/

}


//Fetch an array of affiliates that are within two miles of the user's current location.
- (void)fetchAffiliatesNearPoint:(PFGeoPoint *)geoPoint
{

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Affiliates"];
    [query whereKey:@"geometry" nearGeoPoint:geoPoint withinMiles:2.0];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {
            self.affiliates = objects;
            NSLog(@"Nearby Locations %@", _affiliates);
        }
    }];
}


-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{


    //Zoom map to users current location
    if (!self.initialLocation) {
        self.initialLocation = userLocation.location;
        MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
        mapRegion.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
        mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = .025;
        mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = .025;

        [mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
        }

}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with Parse either but there are a couple of obvious issues that it may be helpful to point out:

1. This line doesn't make sense:

   ```
   for(NSDictionary *affiliates in affiliates)
   ```

   Here, the `affiliates` after `in` refers to the *locally* declared dictionary variable and *not* to the property variable of the same name.  Since the local variable has no initialized reference and is pointing to some random memory, you get the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.  Use `self.affiliates` to refer explicitly to the property.

   Additionally, it's *extremely* confusing to name the looping variable the same as the array it is looping through.  You are looping through an array of "affiliates" (plural).  The array contains dictionaries and each dictionary is an "affiliate" (singular).  It would be less confusing to name the dictionary variable as `affiliate` (singular).  Example:

   ```
   for (NSDictionary *affiliate in self.affiliates)
   ```

   Also change the remaining references inside the loop from `affiliates` to `affiliate`.
2. Currently, the loop on `self.affiliates` is done immediately after `geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground` is *started*.  The `geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground` appears to be asynchronous which means the loop on `self.affiliates` will execute *before* `geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground` has actually set that property.

   Instead of looping through `self.affiliates` in `viewDidLoad` right after  starting `geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground`, move the loop to inside the completion block of `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` (*after* `self.affiliates` is set).  Example:

   ```
   [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
       if (!error)
       {
           self.affiliates = objects;
           NSLog(@"Nearby Locations %@", _affiliates);

           for(NSDictionary *affiliate in self.affiliates) {
               ...
           }
       }
   }];
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.  Making those corrections fixed the memory issues, but sadly I'm still not getting any annotations to display on my map.  At least it is a step in the right direction!

Comment: After the NSLog for "Nearby Locations", add this NSLog and see what it says: `NSLog(@"self.mapView = %@", self.mapView);`.  Also add another NSLog inside the loop right before calling addAnnotation: `NSLog(@"coordinate=%f,%f", annotation.coordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);` and make sure the coordinates are correct and where you expect (also make sure they're not backwards like lat has long and long has lat).

Comment: Interesting...  the first NSLog returns:
self.mapView = <MKMapView: 0x13d60af50; frame = (0 64; 375 603); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x174027520>>

But the second NSLog returns:   coordinate=0.000000,0.000000

Comment: In the "Nearby Locations" NSLog, do the coordinates show correctly in the dictionaries?  If they are correct in the affiliates array but 0,0 in the annotation, then the problem is in the MapAnnotation class.  If they are 0,0 in the affiliates array also, then the data is coming like that from Parse.

Comment: No, the coordinates show in the affiliates array which based on what you mentioned means my MapAnnotaton class is incorrect.

Comment: If still a problem, suggest you post the MapAnnotation class problem as a separate question and include the code for that class.  As just a quick test, you could try switching to using the built-in MKPointAnnotation class instead (`MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];`).

Comment: solution to the missing annotation issue was resolved using information provided in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26834472/4535964

Answer (score 1):

Your custom object must conform to the `MKAnnotation` protocol if you want to add it to the MapKit map. There is only one property you are required to implement to have your object conform to the protocol:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

The rest of the properties (such as `title` and `subtitle`) and methods are optional.

All you need to do is create a category (assuming you're using Objective-C) on PFGeoPoint and implement a getter for the `coordinate` property.

**PFGeoPoint+Annotation.h**

```
@interface PFGeoPoint (Annotation) <MKAnnotation>

@end
```

**PFGeoPoint+Annotation.m**

```
@implementation PFGeoPoint (Annotation)

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.latitude, self.longitude);
}

@end
```

Lastly, to add it to the map, you will use:

```
- (void)addAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation;
```

Ex: `[mapView addAnnotation:geoPoint];`

Comment: Still was not able to piece together a solution based on your answer.  I am new to Obj-C so I may be missing some implied steps that are not explicitly outlined.